# Unable to install add-on that we developed from G-suite marketplace

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Our team has developed an add-on for gmail and it was successfully published to the G suite marketplace. We did all the required and got all the permissions and it is now visible to the public in the marketplace but when we are trying to install the add-on, we are unable to do it. It shows that the installation was successful in marketplace,[image: image showing successful installation in marketplace] 
but it does not show up in the sidebar where it should
[image: image of sidebar with no add-on] 
and nor in the "Installed add-ons" section.[image: image of installed add-ons in settings]

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have an idea on how to debug the issue? If you can point me towards what the problem might be, it would be great.

Please ask for any information needed to debug and I will provide as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi there @starLord073! I have tried to reproduce this situation, but I wasn't able to. To further investigate this scenario, could you please share the minimal replicable add-on code? It would be very helpful if you clarify previous editions of the add-on showed up in the sidebar. Also, when did you pass the G Suite Marketplace publishing process?

Comment: Hey @Jacques-GuzelHeron the name of the add-on is "Achievers for Gmail" (id : achievers-for-gmail-260407) and the publishing process was passed on August 28. Please try to install the add-on on your machine, you can get a better understanding of the issue then. It shows installed in the marketplace but it is not being installed anywhere. Also when installing locally via publish>deploy as manifest in apps script, it is working fine. Please let us know what the reason for this might be. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @starLord073! I was able to install the add-on and check that it doesn't appear on the Gmail sidebar. To check that there is no problem with the code, could you please share the minimal part of the code that shows the button on the sidebar?